# Cinchoo.PGP throwing null reference error when all references are valid

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Cinchoo.PGP to decrypt some files.  When it runs, I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
                using (ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt pgp = new ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt())
                {
                    EncryptionViewModel pem = rpt.Encryption_In;
                    var from = setFiles.FileToProcessPath + setFiles.FileToProcess;
                    var to = setFiles.ProcessedPath + setFiles.ProcessedName;
                    if (from == to)
                    {
                        to = setFiles.ProcessedPath + "_" + setFiles.ProcessedName;
                        pgp.DecryptFile(from, to, pem.PEMPath, pem.PassPhrase);
                        File.Delete(from);
                        File.Move(to, from);
                    }
                    else { pgp.DecryptFile(from, to, pem.PEMPath, pem.PassPhrase); }
                }
```

Stack trace is here:

```
   at Cinchoo.PGP.ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, Stream privateKeyStream, String passPhrase)
   at Cinchoo.PGP.ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt.DecryptFile(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, String privateKeyFilePath, String passPhrase)
   at EDI2.Data.Process_Unencrypt_File.Process(ReportAllDataViewModel rpt) in C:\TWRAProjects\EDI2\EDI2\Data\Data_Process.cs:line 544
```

When I step through the code, all my variables are correct.  My files exist, the pgp reference is valid, my "from" file exists (I manually verified that), my "to" file doesn't exist (same), and my PEMPath and PassPhrase values are populated.

When it runs the pgp.DecryptFile line, however, it throws the "object reference" error.

I'm not sure if I've found a bug in Cinchoo.PGP, or if I am doing something wrong.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks,
Carthax

Comment: We would need to see the stack trace of the exception at least.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Edited

Comment: Since it crashed inside the library I would assume this is some kind of bug with it.

Comment: Which of the two `pgp.DecryptFile` lines is actually used? You might have to reduce your code down to a proof of concept program, hardcoding all paths, etc. just to make sure your way of using the library is supported.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: In this case, the first one.  The file being decrypted needs to keep the same name, so I renamed To to _To, do the decrypt, then delete From, and rename _To to From.